# Run TestNG testcase only on linux

Tags: java, testng, integration-testing

I'm having a test class which uses TestNG. Is there any annotation that I can use to run the testcase only on linux environment?

Ofcourse I can check the os and prevent running. But I think it is easy if there any annotation with TestNG

Comment: TestNG is [documented](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations), you should tell us what running you are trying to prevent (command line via maven, in your IDE, some other running method). The usual methods is to use groups to have OS-specific tests (search for "linux" in the linked doc)

Comment: TestNG is not a framework to run on different oses so I do not understand the need for such an annotation.  It is a general testing framework and you need to write the code for doing specific things you need.

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is to use [`groups`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups). Then, you choose the groups you want when you run your tests.

Another solution is using [Annotation transformers](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers) which will set the [`enabled`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#enabled()) param of `@Test` depending on what you want (environnement in your case).

Your transformer may only activate/desactivate marked tests (with a group, a custom annotation, or what you want) if you doesn't want apply the rule on all tests of your suite.